# Could not parse the remainder: ':' from '1:'

Tags: django, django-templates

**TemplateSyntaxError at /challeges/1**

Could not parse the remainder: ':' from '1:'

This is my **challege.html**

```
{% if month == 1: %}
<h1>This is {{ text }}</h1>
{% else: %}
<p>This is {{ text }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

This is my **views.py**

```
def monthly_challege(request, month):
    return render(request, "challeges/challege.html", {
        "text": "Your Url Is Empty",
        month: month
})
```

This is my **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("<month>", views.monthly_challege),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your if ... else ... statement.
It should be

```
{% if month == 1 %}
    <h1>This is {{ text }}</h1>
{% else %}
    <p>This is {{ text }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

as per doc [if else doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if)

Answer (score 0):

I found it, here is mistake

you have to remove semicolon

```
before
{% if month == 1: %}
<h1>This is {{ text }}</h1>
{% else: %}
<p>This is {{ text }}</p>
{% endif %}


after
{% if month == 1 %}
<h1>This is {{ text }}</h1>
{% else %}
<p>This is {{ text }}</p>
{% endif %}
```